# Resetting mask on CAShapeLayer causes view to briefly appear at full alpha

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer, mask, quartz-core

I have a `UIView` which adds a `CAShapeLayer` as a sublayer to its layer. The `UIView` is at partial alpha. The `CAShapeLayer` is just a solid colored shape. I set the `mask` property of the `CAShapeLayer` to block part of it from being shown, and then reset the `mask` property to `nil` when I want to show the whole shape again:

```
self.shapeLayer.mask = nil
```

Unexpectedly, when I reset the mask of the `CAShapeLayer`, the `UIView` shows at full alpha for maybe half a second. Has anybody run into this before? Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: any chances that you changes alpha somewhere in code ?

Comment: Nope, I double checked that. And it's definitely this line that causes the problem (if I remove it, the alpha stays as expected.)

Comment: have you tried to do the same in animation block ?

Comment: Just tried that, it does the same thing.

Comment: Are you doing all this in the main thread or a background thread?

Comment: This is done on the main thread, I had the same thought and double checked that.

Comment: @Luke please add full code of creating view/layers or test example (I can't reproduce it). BTW, documentation says that when setting mask to new layer it should have nil superlayer. It is not exactly your case, but did you try to remove `shapeLayer` before setting `mask` to `nil` and add it as sublayer after?

Comment: @Luke I tried your case, but i can not get the same result as you. Please show some code.

Comment: Have you tried `CATransaction` ?